# Unable to add my answer link to the 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: support, suggested-edits, election

I am unable to edit the 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire in order to add the link to my answer below the said question. I think it is due to the fact that;

> "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."
>   
> *(I have attached an image below.)*

[image]

How do I add the link to my answers then, or can someone else with perhaps the privileges, add this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [edited](https://meta.askubuntu.com/revisions/18597/10) the question and added the link of your answer.

Comment: I have seen it @Kulfy. Thanks.